# How to get queue related details using AndesAdminService class

Tags: jms, message-queue, wso2, wso2-message-broker

I have created two queues `MyFirstQueue` and `MySecondQueue` in wso2 message broker. I am able to publish and consume messages using sample application given  [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Sending+and+Receiving+Messages+Using+Queues).

Now using wso2 `AndesAdminService` class, I want to fetch queue related information like number of queue created, number of messages in each queue, purge queue and etc..in my code.

I am not getting how should I introduce `AndesAdminService` class in my code? And what other jars will be required ?

I have in my project the following jar files:

1. andes-client-3.1.1.jar
2. geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar
3. log4j-1.2.13.jar
4. org.wso2.carbon.logging-4.4.1.jar
5. org.wso2.securevault-1.0.0-wso2v2.jar
6. slf4j-1.5.10.wso2v1.jar

Please provide me sample code also.

I got AndesAdminService class code [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-business-messaging/blob/master/components/andes/org.wso2.carbon.andes.admin/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/andes/admin/AndesAdminService.java).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need

Comment: Hello @abarisone 
I am using wso2mb as a message brokering system in my project. In wso2mb, I have two queues with name, "MyFirstQueue" and "MySecondQueue". My project requirement is, I have to display information like no. of queues in wso2mb, no. of messages in queue and some more. I know AndesAdminService class provide apis for getting such information. My problem is, I am not sure, how should i use AndesAdminService class in my project. And how many jar is needed to useAndesAdminService? So, I am want any sample example which is using AndesAdminService class, so that i can get reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the WSDL of the admin service. 
Open carbon.xml file and change HideAdminServiceWSDL to false. Then start the server with -DosgiConsole parameter. Type listAdminServices in the console. There you can get the list of admin services available and their WSDL urls.
Then create a stub out of the WSDL using axis2 or some other bindings.
Then use that generated stub and call the necessary methods.